# forwarded domain with cloaking jquery tabs- jQuery1.9.1: -Error: Permission denied to access object

Tags: cross-domain, jquery-tabs

I have a domain that is forwarded with cloaking to a subdomain in godaddy(dk if that matters). Each browser renders these in a frame differently. Chrome and Safari render the jquery tabs and are error free, but IE 9 and Firefox 20. don't render the jquery tabs and the error in Firefox firebug is:

```
Error: Permission denied to access object
[Break On This Error]   
class2type[ core_toString.call(obj) ] || "object" :
```

A javascript slideshow that I have in one of the tabs plays fine. I have seen some reference to x-frame options but this is not all on the same host so I don't see how setting them would help.

The url is pop67theshow.com - the actual location of the files is at pop67.equatorproductions.net and there is no problem without the domain cloaking.

Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue using JavaScript to detect screen sizes.

Accessing www.example.com/mypage.html works fine, but when the site is put behind a cloak (www.what-the-user-sees.com --> www.example.com/mypage.html), it cannot get the user's system details and just presents the desktop-size page to all devices.

Check if you are accessing any objects on the client-side, as they may be hidden by the cloaking.

Looking at the page now, perhaps you've already found a workaround/this was not the issue. Anyway, here's what (some) providers' cloaking could look like to the client browser:

```
<html>
<frame src="http://www.domain.com/mypage.html">
<noframes>
<body>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
        <!--
        document.location.href = 'http://www.domain.com/mypage.html'
        //-->
        </script>
</body>
</noframes>
</html>
```